# Proof about independent random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent random variables with $P(X_n=1)=p_n$ and $P(X_n=0)=1-p_n$

1. Show that $X_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability if and only if $p_n\rightarrow0$,
2. $X_n\rightarrow 0$ almost surely if and only if $\sum p_n<\infty$.

Unfortunately I don't have any idea how to solve this, so I am thankful for any useful tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For 1.** According to the definition of convergence in probability, $X_n \overset{p} \to X$ iff $$P(|X_n-X|>\epsilon) \to 0$$ as $n\to \infty$. But since $X_n$ is equal either to $0$ or to $1$ you have for $X\equiv0$ and for all $\epsilon>0$ that: $$P(|X_n-0|>\epsilon)=P(X_n=1)=p_n$$ which obviously converges to $0$ if and only if $p_n \to 0$.

**For 2.** If $\sum p_n < \infty$ then this is equivalent to $$\sum p_n=\sum P(|X_n-0|>\epsilon)<0$$ thus $X_n$ converges [almost completely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Sure_convergence) (or simply completely) to $0$ and it is a direct implication of the first [Borel-Cantelli Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma) that then also $$X_n \overset{a.s.}\to 0$$ or almost surely. Now use that the $X_n$'s are independent, thus the events $E_n:=\{X_n:=1\}$ are also independent and apply the second Borel-Cantelli Lemma to see that the other direction (in the if and only if statement) holds also true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am trying to understand your proof of 1). I dont understand the sentence "But since $X_n$ is equal to one or zero..." and the steps after this. Can you explain it to me in more detail please?

Comment: X_n takes only two values, 0 and 1. So $P(X_n>ε)=P(X_n=1)$.

Comment: Thats the thing I don't understand. I am sorry for this probably stupid question. But why $X_n$ does only take two values?

Comment: Probably then you have just copied the exercise from somewhere then, without having read it! It is in the text that you posted, first line top right... $P(X_n=0)$ and $P(X_n=1)$. No other values.

Comment: But what about the $p_n$?I thought this notation does mean: $P(X_n=0)=P(X_n^{-1}(0))=p_n$ I thought thats just a property on a certain set and we don't know anything about the other values. I am reading it like: "The measure of the fiber under all $X_n$ of zero is exactly $p_n$"

Comment: It does not fit that you are doing probability theory with convergence, Borel-Cantelli etc, and you do not know basic notation. What you are asking is elementary notation. I am sorry.

Comment: Okay, i got it know. Last question:Why are you only considering $X=0$ and not also $X=1$? If all $X_n=1$ or $1$, then X could be 1 too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18147/discussion-between-stefanos-and-epsilondelta).